# How to get month from sql date and check month is equal to the passing parameter month using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

Using below function for getting month of sql date.But I didnt get the correct information ,Its shows exception ,anyone Please help me

```
 public static List<data> getCount(Long month,String activity) 
                {    
            session = HibernateUtils.getHibernateConnection();
                            Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Statement.class, "statement");
                            Criteria text = c.createAlias("activity", "activity");
                            c.add(Restrictions.eq("activity.defintionType",activity));
                            c.add(Restrictions.eq("month(statement.stored)",month));
         alist= c.list();
    }
```

Comment: Which exception ... ?

Comment: c.add(Restrictions.eq("month(statement.stored)",month)); exception is: This is not correct format ,

Comment: Edit your question with the complete StackTrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
c.add(Restrictions.eq("month(statement.stored)",month));
```

to this:

```
c.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("month(stored) = ? ", 1,Hibernate.INTEGER));
```

Assuming the supplied month argument is of a numeric type.

Comment: thanks for ur comments.But ur solution is not working.I have found another solution. c.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("month(stored) = ? ", 1,Hibernate.INTEGER)); This one is working